# Validate image type with fake extension

Tags: jquery, image, validation

I try to create a real file type validation with JQuery. I want to check if my image is a JPG or a PNG. Here is my function :

```
function validate_file(file) {
    if(file.type.match("image/jpeg") || file.type.match("image/png")) {
     return true;
    }
    else {
      alert("Formats supportés : jpeg et png");
      return false;
    }
}
```

"exemple_1.jpg" is true and "exemple_2.pdf" is false. If I rename my second file like "exemple_2.jpg" it's true... but has to be false !

I would like to test if the file is a real JPG or PNG. My image is draw on an HTML5 canvas.

Any idea ?

**UPDATE :**

Here is the function that load the image

```
img.onload = function() {
    // Resize images (width)
    if (img.width > max_width) {
        ratio = max_width / img.width;
        width = max_width;
        height = img.height * ratio;
    }
    else {
        width = img.width;
    }

    // Resize images (height)
    if (img.height > max_height) {
        ratio = max_height / img.height;
        height = max_height;
        width = img.width * ratio;
    } 
    else {
        height = img.height;
    }

    // Adjust canvas
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    // Draw canvas
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
    url.revokeObjectURL(src);

}
```

Comment: you could try to read the first few bytes, otherwise, catch the exception.

Comment: Is this for files you're letting users upload?

Comment: Checking the mime type with javascript is unreliable, as you have probably discovered. Changing the extension makes it validate. The only reliable way to check the mime type is on the serverside, where you can parse parts of the file to make sure you get the right mime type.

Comment: @adeneo I know it's possible, the website 500px.com do it with jQuery. I think the way to do it is to catch an exception but I don't know how...

Comment: @DanielA.White I have no exception, I can't catch it. The canvas try to draw but return no error

Comment: Yes it's for users upload

Comment: Did you try the accept attribute on the element -> `<input type="file" accept="image/*" />`, but I'm pretty sure any website, like 500px.com, has serverside validation of mime types, otherwise someone with a little skills could upload all sorts of crap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tips (maybe not the best solution)

I add a second canvas :

```
<canvas id="canvas_preview"></canvas>
<canvas id='blank' style='display:none'></canvas>
```

And check if my main canvas looks like the blank one. I write this code in my 'fadeIn' callback :

```
$("#canvas_preview").delay(2700).fadeIn(
    1500, 
    function(){ 
        if(document.getElementById("canvas_preview").toDataURL() == document.getElementById('blank').toDataURL()) {
            alert("Bad jpg");
        }
    }
);
```

Thanks everybody !

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This question was about serverside validation when I answered this question. My answer stands - never ever trust the client to send you proper data! You can validate clientside for nice UX, but you should validate serverside too.

You could try using ImageMagick's identify command or the Linux `file` command to see what the file's type is:

For actual JPGs:

```
$ file IMAG0108.jpg
IMAG0108.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
$ identify IMAG0108.jpg
IMAG0108.jpg JPEG 480x852 480x852+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 75.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

For PDFs renamed to JPGs:

```
$ mv CCF04262013.pdf CCF04262013.jpg
$ file CCF04262013.jpg
CCF04262013.jpg: PDF document, version 1.3
$ identify CCF04262013.jpg
CCF04262013.jpg PDF 595x775 595x775+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 58.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Just shell out, run the command, check the output, and off you go. Make sure that the user cannot pass arbitrary filenames as a part of the shell-out (use tempfiles).

Comment: It's a good idea, but It's impossible because the image is on a Canvas so it's client side :)

Comment: I don't think you can get access to the raw unprocessed bytes in the browser, which you would need in order to validate the file type. MIME may be the best you can do.

Comment: I agree. Maybe it's possible to catch the exception. I just update my post with the load function. If you have any idea. Thanks.

Comment: sorry for late answer, of course I have Server Side Validation to ;) Thanks